# cocoapods install fails on mac OS Mojave

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, macos-mojave

Trying to install cocoapods on OS Mojave with Xcode 11.0, 
`sudo gem install cocoapods` installs 30 gems. Next, when I click `pod setup` it does nothing.

Any solution to that I am new to Xcode and macOS.

Answer (score 0):

Let me tell step by step

1. First install cocoapods by opening terminal and type `sudo gem install cocoapods`

2.then `pod setup` it will do nothing,
3.then type `cd` in terminal followed by project directory (drag and drop)
4.then type `pod install` . This will install all pods.